# "User"-folder is larger than contents

Tags: macos, finder

My "user" folder is about 56GB big, but when I look at the contents (and add them up with a calculator) I get up to about 24GB. What happened to the other 32GB? Is there a way to free this space up?

I have a hidden folder called `.rvm` with the size of almost 3GB. My Library is almost 30GB though, can I remove something in there? It seems excessively big!

[image]
[image]

Edit: So, these are the biggest folders in my Library. Is there a way to get some space back, or do I just have to learn to live with this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one place you haven't listed is your Library folder..

From the Finder menu choose `GO`

[image]

then `Go To Folder`

[image]

```
 ~/Library
```

The chances are your Application Support directory has loads of stuff stashed.

Comment: I named my Library-folder in the question, maybe not clear enough that it's the hidden Library, not music. However, that folder is almost 30GB big with these as the biggest culprits: http://i62.tinypic.com/2mevokl.png. How do I get some of the space back? It's only a 128GB SSD :P

Comment: Also, it's easier to get to the Library by clicking on Go and holding `alt` :)

Comment: I have alt re-tasked so forgat that shortcut a lot

Comment: Ah ok! But, any way to get some of the space back?

Comment: There are apps on the app store that will help locate space hogs and help delete them. I use Disk Doctor https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/disk-doctor/id455970963?mt=12

Comment: Thanks, saved a whopping 1.5GB! Haha! Well, at least is something. I guess it's time to invest in a USB 3.0 stick or external HDD.